# "The parameter is incorrect" when trying to execute installers from shared drive

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders, unc

We have a WD MyCloud device that we use for a public share.  When I deploy new PCs about half of them have this issue. If I browse the network to the public share (via name) and run an installer, I get the message `The parameter is incorrect`. I have to copy the exe to the desktop and run it.  Suspecting it might be DNS, I have also tried navigating via UNC using the IP address. I get the same results, it works on some machines but not others (we're talking brand new Dell laptops, some are even the same model).  Mapping a drive doesn't help either.

```
[Window Title]
\\10.1.0.20\public\Installs\Notepad++\npp.7.9.5.Installer.exe

[Content]
\\10.1.0.20\public\Installs\Notepad++\npp.7.9.5.Installer.exe

The parameter is incorrect.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The issue absolutely isn’t a DNS issue

Comment: Are you right-clicking and running the installer as administrator? Or tried running it from an elevated command prompt? Does the public share have a username / password to access it? Are these truly out of box new PCs? Or have you performed other deployment tasks, such as reloading the OS? Or deploying from an image?

Comment: I've tried running as admin. No username and password for the share. It's set to "public" in the WD interface.  Out of the box, OS from Dell.